# My SQL code doesn't give me all the data I need

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

```
select distinct  
    max(A.awardyear) AS 'Award Year',  
    max(S.SSN) AS 'Student Social Security Number',  
    max(S.firstname) AS 'Student First Name',  
    max(S.lastname) AS 'Student Last Name',  
    max(D.birthdate) as 'Student Date of Birth',  
    max(M.OPEID) as 'Instituion Code',  
    max(M.Schoolname) as 'Institution Name',  
    max(Q.programtitle) as 'Program Name',   
    max(Q.CIPCode) as 'CIPCode',  
    max(Q.[Award Document]) as 'Credential Level',  
    case  
       WHEN q.[Award Document] = 'diploma'  
         then '01'  
       else '02'  
    end,  
    max(I.[1stSite]) as 'Medical or Dental internship',  
    min(A.AYStartDate) as 'Program attendance begin date',  
    max(y.EnStatus) as 'Program attendance status',  
    max(y.NewGradDate) as 'Program attendance status date',  
    case  
       when y.NewGradDate > '2009-06-30'  
         then '2009-06-30'  
         else y.NewGradDate  
    end,  
    min(A.AYStartDate) as 'program attendance begin date for this award year',  
    max(R.programtotal) as 'Tuition & fees',  
    max(R.AYSupplies + R.AYBooks + R.AYUniform) as 'allowance for books, supplies,      and equipment',  
    max(P.programlength) as 'Length of GE program'  
from 
    studentinfo s  
inner join 
    awardletter a ON A.studentid = S.studentid  
inner join 
    budget r on A.budgetid = r.budgetid  
inner join 
    studentdata d on D.studentid = s.studentid  
inner join 
    TranscriptInformation t on t.studentid = s.studentid  
inner join 
    attendance e on e.studentid = s.studentid  
inner join 
    ProgLengthCalc p on p.studentid = s.studentid  
inner join 
    programs q on q.program = p.program  
inner join 
    Schools m on m.school = s.school  
inner join 
    enrollmentinformation y on y.studentid = s.studentid  
left join 
    internship i on i.studentid = s.studentid  
where 
    A.awardyear = '08/09'  
group by 
    a.awardyear, a.awardyear, s.ssn, s.firstname, s.lastname, d.birthdate, 
    m.opeid, m.schoolname, q.programtitle, q.cipcode, q.[Award Document], 
    i.[1stSite], a.aystartdate, y.EnStatus, y.NewGradDate, e.date, 
    r.programtotal, r.AYSupplies + r.aybooks + r.ayuniform, p.programlength
```

What's happening is my code is only returning 18 rows, when in all reality there are 2,000 plus just for this 08/09 award year. I need this dense code to work for all award years up to 13/14, and it isn't.

I'm not sure if there is a restriction I have put in my code that's making is down to 18 rows. I'm fairly new to SQL Server Management Studio and I know there is a bulk amount of inner join's, but I need them all for this dense amount of data.

Any suggestions? Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Without knowing your desired results or sample data, it looks like the problem is that you are aggregating the same columns you are grouping by.   Why would you only want the MAX social security number, for instance?

Comment: Its impossible to answer to that without the data, you have a lot of dependencies between the tables, any join/where/groupby can narrow down your results

Comment: I'd say there's a 99.99999% chance your group by clause is wrong or more likely not needed

Comment: @Amit so if It's wrong, what should i do instead?

Comment: Start by removing it. See what you get. Continue from there

Comment: @amit it's telling me that it cannot load since some things aren't in a aggregate or group by statement...

Comment: Now remove all aggregation functions... Honestly, it feels like your trying to run an obstacle race before you've learned how to walk. You should study SQL before building such a query

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the max of each. So, in your code above you have 18 select max statements. It is taking the max from the 2000 or so rows for each column thus giving you 18 columns. Try removing the max's.

Comment: did this, still got the same results

Comment: Try removing the distinct as well so it is just a select.

Comment: The last suggestion I have is max everything in your code except the Student Social Security number, just select that. Now you will only have to group by student social security number. If each of the 2000 rows represents a unique student with a unique social security number it should not merge any of the rows and you should see all 2000 of your rows. If you don't see all of your rows still look into the inner joins. An inner join does not show a row if the condition of the join is not met.

Comment: So, if any of your inner join conditions are not met on a row then the entire row is not shown as a result of your query. If this is not your intention try left joins. A left or outer join. That will retain all of your rows even if the criteria of the join is not met. When it is not met the row will simply not pull in the column information from the table it is being joined to.

Comment: I did left joins and got the amount of rows i want, but now for some i'm getting NULL values where there shouldn't be

Comment: the ones i'm getting NULL's for have to do with the two join's that aren't associated with the studentid ( inner join programs q on q.program = p.program ). What did i do wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting NULL's for all of the rows or only some of them? What values are you getting incorrect NULL's for?

Comment: i'm getting NULL's for all rows, except like 2-4 out of 5000. This has to have been the root of all my problems! It is actually these two joins (inner join 
    ProgLengthCalc p on p.studentid = s.studentid  
inner join 
    programs q on q.program = p.program ) that aren't correct, but I thought I put them together well. The ProgLengthCalc has the studentid within it, as well as the program, programlength. So I joined it to get the length of the program, then joined the programs table to ProgLengthCalc using the (program) column.

Comment: and my NULL's are for the following columns: Program Name, CIPCode, Credential Level, & Length of GE Program

Comment: I would check for reasons why the join isn't joining the data properly. Maybe q.program doesn't match p.program in most cases due to added spaces? It could be any amount of discrepancies. If you have found my answers helpful could you mark my answer as the answer?

Comment: yup, I figured that out yesterday, I was just connected two wrong tables! very simple yet gave me a headache for all the effort! hah, but thanks a lot @hayes for all your help much appreciated